# Calling Oracle procedure from entity framework with boolean output parameter

Tags: oracle, entity-framework

I am attempting to call a stored procedure in an Oracle 11g Database using Entity Framework 6. The signature of the procedure is as this:

`PROCEDURE_NAME(param1 IN varchar2, param2 IN varchar2, result OUT boolean)`

I've attempted using both the shorter version, using ExecuteSqlCommand, and the verbose version using CreateCommand, as follows:

```
var result = new OracleParameter("result", OracleDbType.Boolean, ParameterDirection.Output)
{
    Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output
};
var parameters = new[] {
    new OracleParameter("param1", param1),
    new OracleParameter("param2", param2)
    result
};

using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
using (var cmd = ctx.Database.Connection.CreateCommand() as OracleCommand)
{
    try
    {
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.CommandText = "PROCEDURE_NAME";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddRange(parameters);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    finally
    {
        cmd.Connection.Close();
    }
}
```

This throws an execption, `ORA-03115: unsupported network datatype or representation`
I'm *guessing* it has to do with the boolean, as that is typically messy when it comes to Oracle, but cannot find a way around it. Unfortunately I can't modify the procedure, which would've been the obvious choice. Attempting to change the OracleDbType to an integer or a char, as some other posts have advised, instead throws an exception for incorrect data type.

Comment: Upvoted for *"is typically messy when it comes to Oracle"* :) See if the suggested workaround with anonymous block works for you.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not. It is then instead telling me there's syntax errors, even though the anonymous block runs just fine when entered directly into SQL Developer.

Comment: Please update the question with your attempt. This would eventually allow reopening it.